# How do enzymes use quantum tunneling (also, please use relatively simple vocabulary)?

Tags: quantum-tunneling

I already know how the Sun uses quantum tunneling to create nuclear fusion, but can't apply it to enzymes. Also, since I'm only in eighth grade, please use relatively simple language. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reference supporting the claim that enzymes use tunneling?

Comment: Sorry. Those answers didn't help StephenG. And Daniel: https://sciencenode.org/feature/natures-subway-quantum-tunneling-enzymes.php

Comment: Does anyone have any possible solutions?

Comment: You need to explain what you don't understand from the other answer.